# Archive/export all the blog entries from a RSS feed in Google Reader

Tags: google-reader, export

Is there a way to export or archive all the blog posts from a feed in Google Reader?

Sometimes blogs get deleted, but Google Reader still manages to save much of their content.

How can I export those blog entries off of that blog an onto a hard disk?

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but it should certainly be possible.  The 'Reeder for iPad' application somehow manages to pull in the data from Google Reader.  Also see this page.  http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/w/list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After logging to Google Reader, you can download the last 1000 items of each feed using the url [http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/[feed_address]?n=1000](http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/%5Bfeed_address%5D?n=1000). If you need to archive more than 1000 items, you have to follow [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=29c0f8a4afeced25&hl=en) procedure (the key word is "continuation parameter").

Answer (score 2):

You could always access the raw XML of the feeds and create your own method to parse them and save the important sections to disk.

Something like [this Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/p/tpgooglereader/source/browse/wiki/Features.wiki?spec=svn38&r=38#) is helpful in accessing the XML for different feeds that you have active in the reader.

Having this raw information will get you whatever content that the blog was exposing to the world, but it won't necessarily get the entire blog from top to bottom. Running something like [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) *would* allow you to download the entire blog for offline viewing.

Comment: Hm I see - thanks for all the info! I was more thinking of doing something like downloading the entire blog if it got deleted (or if the server crashed) - since I subscribe to hundreds of feeds, and probably wouldn't have the time to manually do it for each feed - but would do it if the blog got deleted (which has happened before)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing a couple of days ago, so I put together this simple script: https://code.google.com/p/getgrfeed/

The script can be used to download the entirety of a single feed stored in Google Reader. For instance, if I wanted to dump the feed for BoingBoing, I'd run it like this:

```
$ python getgrfeed.py http://feeds.boingboing.net/boingboing/iBag
```

It will then start printing every entry Google Reader has stored. Of course, BoingBoing is a busy site, so it would take a while, but it should work. This is useful especially to save a copy of blog entries -- or entire sites -- that no longer exist anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

[RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/) also is able to retrieve the last 1000 items of each feed you have subscribed in Google Reader.